# VBA to skip consecutive occurence of events

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I have an Excel data table with the following contents:

1st row:  table headers

A2:A50001 event dates

B2:B50001 numbers (CRITERIA 1)

C2:C50001 numbers (CRITERIA 2)

E2:E50001 target cells (FLAG 1)

D2:D50001 target date 1

G2:G50001 target cells (FLAG 2)

F2:F50001 target date 2

note: A2:G50001 may contain cells with errors or blanks

I would like to perform a routine task as
when value of criteria 2 was greater than value of criteria 1
and value of criteria 1 was greater than value of criteria 1 of previous row
then add "FLAG 1" to cell of same row on column E
when value of criteria 2 was smaller than of equal to value of criteria 1
and value of criteria 1 was smaller than of equal to value of criteria 1 of previous row
then add "FLAG 2" to cell of same row on column G

Here I wrote an MACRO for this

```
Sub add_flag_with_criteria_1_2()

Dim i As Integer
Dim Dt As Long 'this line added
Dim Cr1 As Long
Dim Cr2 As Long
Dim flag1 As Long
Dim flag2 As Long
Dim F1date As Long
Dim F2date As Long
Dim F1roof As Long
Dim F2roof As Long
Dim LR As Long 'this line added
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("CRITERIA")

LR = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Range("A1:A50001")) 'this line added
Dt = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Date", ws.Range("1:1"), 0) 'this line added
Cr1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("CRITERIA1", ws.Range("1:1"), 0)
Cr2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("CRITERIA2", ws.Range("1:1"), 0)
flag1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("flag1", ws.Range("1:1"), 0)
flag2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("flag2", ws.Range("1:1"), 0)
F1date = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("F1date", ws.Range("1:1"), 0)
F2date = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("F2date", ws.Range("1:1"), 0) 

For i = 2 To LR
F1roof = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ws.Range(Cells(2, 4), Cells(i, 4))) 'this line added
F2roof = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ws.Range(Cells(2, 6), Cells(i, 6))) 'this line added
If Cells(i, Cr2) > Cells(i, Cr1) And Cells(i, Cr1) > Cells(i - 1, Cr1) And Not F2roof < F1roof Then Cells(i, F1date).Value = Cells(i, Dt).Value
If Cells(i, Cr2) > Cells(i, Cr1) And Cells(i, Cr1) > Cells(i - 1, Cr1) And Not F2roof < F1roof Then Cells(i, flag1).Value = "FLAG1"
If Cells(i, Cr2) <= Cells(i, Cr1) And Cells(i, Cr1) <= Cells(i - 1, Cr1) And Not F1roof < F2roof Then Cells(i, F2date).Value = Cells(i, Dt).Value
If Cells(i, Cr2) <= Cells(i, Cr1) And Cells(i, Cr1) <= Cells(i - 1, Cr1) And Not F1roof < F2roof Then Cells(i, flag2).Value = "FLAG2"
Next


End Sub
```

I have 2 major issues here.

1. my data with numbers may only reaches row 3XXXX or something, cells below the last row with numbers may be left as errors or blanks.  Should I handle this with an application.worksheetfunction.counta and replace the last row (50001) with an variable?
2. I would like to make the occurrence of flag 1 and flag 2 alternative.  I.e. if flag 1 occurs consecutively before the next flag 2, the second flag 1 will not be added (like if flag 1 occurred at 3/3/2020 and 5/3/2020 while flag 2 occurred at 2/3/2020 and 8/3/2020, flag 1 will not be added to 5/3/2020).  What code should I add for this logic?

Thank you.

Comment: You should really ask one question per, er, question. (1) Yes use a variable (2) Perhaps use a boolean to check if last flag was 1 or 2.

Comment: Btw couldn't you do this with formulae?

Comment: I originally wrote this excel template solely with formulae.  I found I often need to modify the logics to suit the tasks and started thinking of vba.  vba is kind of difficult to me, but I would like to try more coding for interest.

Comment: I try modified the code as above.  The lines for F1roof and F2roof (with which I tried to calculate the last flag's date for comparison) resulted in "Unable to get the Max property of the WorksheetFunction class".  What was my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try.  Applied more descriptive names and moved declarations closer to where they are used.

```
Option Explicit

Sub add_flag_with_criteria_1_2()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets.[_Default]("CRITERIA")

    Dim dateColumn As Long
    dateColumn = GetColumnNumber(ws, "Date")

    Dim criteria1Column As Long
    criteria1Column = GetColumnNumber(ws, "CRITERIA1")

    Dim criteria2Column As Long
    criteria2Column = GetColumnNumber(ws, "CRITERIA2")

    Dim flag1Column As Long
    flag1Column = GetColumnNumber(ws, "flag1")

    Dim flag2Column As Long
    flag2Column = GetColumnNumber(ws, "flag2")

    Dim flag1DateColumn As Long
    flag1DateColumn = GetColumnNumber(ws, "F1date")

    Dim flag2DateColumn As Long
    flag2DateColumn = GetColumnNumber(ws, "F2date")

    Dim flag1DateRoof As Long
    Dim flag2DateRoof As Long

    Dim flagToApply As Long
    flagToApply = 0

    Dim rowIndex As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Long

    lastRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Range("A1:A50001"))

    For rowIndex = 2 To lastRow
        If Not IsBlankOrError(ws, rowIndex, criteria1Column, criteria2Column) Then
            flag1DateRoof = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ws.Range(Cells.Item(2, 4), Cells.Item(rowIndex, 4)))

            flag2DateRoof = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ws.Range(Cells.Item(2, 6), Cells.Item(rowIndex, 6)))

            If Not flag2DateRoof < flag1DateRoof And flagToApply <> 1 Then

                If ws.Cells.Item(rowIndex, criteria2Column).Value > ws.Cells.Item(rowIndex, criteria1Column).Value And Cells.Item(rowIndex, criteria1Column) > Cells.Item(rowIndex - 1, criteria1Column) Then

                    If flagToApply = 0 Then flagToApply = 1

                    ws.Cells.Item(rowIndex, flag1DateColumn).Value = ws.Cells.Item(rowIndex, dateColumn).Value
                    flagToApply = ApplyFlagValue(flagToApply, flag1Column, flag2Column, rowIndex)
                End If
            End If


            If Not flag1DateRoof < flag2DateRoof And flagToApply <> 2 Then
                If ws.Cells.Item(rowIndex, criteria2Column) <= ws.Cells.Item(rowIndex, criteria1Column) And ws.Cells.Item(rowIndex, criteria1Column) <= ws.Cells.Item(rowIndex - 1, criteria1Column) Then

                    If flagToApply = 0 Then flagToApply = 2

                    ws.Cells.Item(rowIndex, flag2DateColumn).Value = ws.Cells.Item(rowIndex, dateColumn).Value
                    flagToApply = ApplyFlagValue(flagToApply, flag1Column, flag2Column, rowIndex)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Private Function IsBlankOrError(ws As Worksheet, ByVal rowIndex As Long, ByVal criteria1Column As Long, ByVal criteria2Column As Long) As Boolean
    IsBlankOrError = False
    If IsBlank(ws.Cells.Item(rowIndex, criteria1Column)) Or IsBlank(ws.Cells.Item(rowIndex, criteria2Column)) Then
        IsBlankOrError = True
    ElseIf IsError(ws.Cells.Item(rowIndex, criteria1Column)) Or IsError(ws.Cells.Item(rowIndex, criteria2Column)) Then
        IsBlankOrError = True
    End If
End Function

Private Function ApplyFlagValue(ByVal flagToApply As Long, ByVal flag1Column As Long, ByVal flag2Column As Long, ByVal rowIndex As Long) As Long

    Dim flagToApplyNext As Long
    If flagToApply = 1 Then
        Cells.Item(rowIndex, flag1Column).Value = "FLAG1"
        flagToApplyNext = 2
    Else
        Cells.Item(rowIndex, flag2Column).Value = "FLAG2"
        flagToApplyNext = 1
    End If

    ApplyFlagValue = flagToApplyNext
End Function

Private Function GetColumnNumber(ws As Worksheet, headerLabel As String) As Long
    GetColumnNumber = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(headerLabel, ws.Range("1:1"), 0)
End Function

Private Function IsBlank(theCell As Range) As Boolean
    IsBlank = Trim(theCell.Value) = ""
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your code.  It was very enlightening.

Comment: hi @BZngr, I have a question on top of the code you provided.
I would like to add another logic for generation of flag1, in which flag1 will be give only when value of criteria2column at row i was smaller than the value of criteria1column at row i-5.
I want to to this by another private function as Boolean but I found that I may be incorrect.  May you have a look of my added lines below?

Comment: Private Function compare_w_timeago(ws As Worksheet, rowindex As Range, lastROW As Long) As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets.[_Default]("CRITERIA")
    lastROW = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Range("A1:A50001"))
    For rowindex = 2 To lastROW
compare_w_timeago = ws.Cells.Item(rowindex, criteria2column).Value < ws.Cells.Item(rowindex - 5, criteria2column).Value
Next
End Function

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, but the code in your comment uses `rowindex - 5` which will only be valid starting in row 6.  So, perhaps your loop needs to be `For rowindex = 6 to lastROW`.

Comment: thanks for your reply.  I actually modified the loop starting from row 10.  And I think I am not quite familiar with how to use the codes.  May be I shall come back to this question again after some tidy up.

Comment: hi @BZngr, before I proceed to further development on the code, I noticed a problem which warrant correction first.  After testing with different sets of data, I found that the code assigned flags and date wrongly.  Some rows had flag1 but with flag2date, and vice versa.

Comment: @JohnLiu, took another look at your #2 issue description.  Modified the code to apply the flags and values as I understand the requirement (see additions of logic `And flagToApply <> x`.  Without actual data it is difficult to say, but hopefully the changes produce the results that you are expecting.  Good luck!